# Concatenating SQL query code from an Excel spreadsheet - How to handle apostrophes?

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to concatenate several columns of an excel spreadsheet to generate lines of code for an sql query, as such:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OrderDetail 
WHERE od_MillNum = 505
  AND od_CreatedDate > '2022-01-01'
  AND (od_StyleDesc LIKE ('%Accentuate%') 
    OR od_StyleDesc LIKE ('%Acclaimed%')
    OR od_StyleDesc LIKE ('%Accomplishment%')
    OR od_StyleDesc LIKE ('%A La Mode%'))
  AND od_ProductCode = 5
  AND od_LineType = 'SL'
```

I'm trying to reproduce the od_StyleDescript line for over 300 different styles, as listed in a column of my spreadsheet. I created a column to hold the first part of the code (od_StyleDesc LIKE ('%) and another to hold the last part (%')) and used the CONCAT function to piece together the three columns.

The problem is that some of the styles use an apostrophe (ie Designer's Choice). Is there an easy way to catch those or do I need to check line by line to add in an escape character for each apostrophe?

Comment: Do you use Power Automate to query an Excel spreadsheet data using SQL ?